# How do i fetch the custom headers in java which is set in node js or sent by nodejs

Tags: java, node.js, rest, httpconnection

Frontend pass the request to nodejs application and nodejs pass the request call to JAVA.
I am using following code to authenticate my REST apis and make connection to the specified url.
I want to add or print the custom headers passed in request.

```
public HttpURLConnection establishConnection(String baseurl, String methodtype, String userId,
        HttpHeaders headers) {
    URL url;
    JSONObject userInfo=new JSONObject();
    try {
        url = new URL(baseurl);
        output = "";
        userInfo=getUserName(headers.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION));
        String userpass=null;
        if (userId.isEmpty())
            userpass = userInfo.getString("username") + ":" + userInfo.getString("password");
        else
            userpass = userId + ":" + userInfo.getString("password");

        String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(userpass.getBytes()));
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization",basicAuth);
        conn.setRequestMethod(methodtype);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setConnectTimeout(60000); // 60 seconds
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        return conn;
```

}
}

How do i fetch the custom headers passed in request ? Which method should i use ? or Class that i can use to fetch the custom headers.

Answer (score 0):

using @HeaderParam("customparamname") String param , with this param @HeaderParam i m able to get custom parameter value.